# Изменить параграф на Input vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при клике к примеру на `<p>Нажми меня</p>` превратить его в `<input>Нажми меня</input>` и при клике на Enter или фокуса вывести сообщение в консоль ?

У меня есть вывод значений из базы Имя, Фамилия,Отчество для отображения пользователю,

```
<div class="col-md-8"> 
  <div class="card-body"> 
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ api.attributes.surname }}</h4> 
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ api.attributes.name }}</h4> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Вот хотелось бы при клике на имя иметь сразу же возможность редактировании этого поля и записи его в базу

Comment: `<input>` - это одиночный тег, а не контейнер. Вы пробовали читать про теги хоть какую-то документацию?

Comment: Есть возможность реализовать такое ?

Comment: Какое- такое? Из одиночного тега, сделать контейнер? Нет! То что вы хотите сделать, делается через `<input placeholder="Нажми меня">`.

Comment: [Обработка событий](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) почитайте, тут все детально описано, вам нужно по вешать событие `v-on:click` и реализовать метод, в котором будете заменять 1 элемент на другой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того как это можно сделать с одним полем:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    first_name: 'First Name',
    firstNameEdit: false,
  },
  methods: {
   submit(){
     console.log(this.first_name);
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="firstNameEdit">
      <input v-model="first_name" v-on:keyup.enter="submit" v-on:keyup.escape="firstNameEdit = false">
  </div>
  <div v-else v-on:click="firstNameEdit = true">
    {{first_name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

При клике на h1 мы переключаем логическую переменную, которая отвечает что мы показываем (h1 или input)

При нажатии на enter когда input в фокусе, сработает метод submit

При нажатии на escape вы можете закрыть input